# Displaying Android DialogFragment from Unity doesn't look as it should

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've created an Android library that displays a DialogFragment.

If I use it inside an Android Native App, it works fine, but if the same DialogFragment is displayed from a Unity App (as a plugin), the UI doesn't look as it should.

Is there any way I can make Unity display it the same as a Native App?

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog` in android uses default theme of the `App` and this could be different for native vs unity app, in order to maintain consistency, I would recommend to use a custom theme to design your dialog and ship the theme along with library so it overrides the theme of Unity app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Customized theme used in both native and unity app -->
    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor"></item>
        <item name="android:typeface"></item>
        <item name="android:textSize"></item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And while building dialog use it as

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.DialogTheme))
```

Comment: The main difference is in layout and font sizes (that are inside the layout XML), do you think the theme will still matter?

Comment: it depends on how UI is behaving differently on unity compared to native, screenshots of both would help pinning down the root cause!